# No output when listening on USB bus with usbmon

Tags: linux, debugging, usb, kernel

I have a USB HID device that I'm trying to intercept data from. I'm using Linux, and to my understanding the right tool for the job is the usbmon kernel driver. I'm currently following the official documentation at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt, but I've encountered a problem that is not mentioned there.

My problem is that usbmon is not showing any data for my USB device, even though I'm listening on the same bus that the device is reported to be connected to. I have verified that the device is working by testing it in Windows where I have official drivers.

What I've done so far:

1. Loaded the usbmon kernel driver (modprobe usbmon)
2. Verified that all bus sockets are present (# ls /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon)
3. Ran lsusb to verify which bus my device is on (Bus 006 Device 002)

My current setup is:

- Distro: Arch Linux
- Kernel: Linux 3.17.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 30 20:49:39 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When I run "# cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/6u", which would allow me to look at the events from the USB device, I get no output. What could be causing this? Am I missing an additional kernel driver to get it working?

Comment: How do you know you are looking at the right device?  Try some other channels to see if there is any activity.

Comment: @wallyk I verified the correct bus and device ID using lsusb. I have gotten a bit further on this project though. It seems like the device sends no output until it receives the first report from the host. I used usblyzer on Windows when I used the offical drivers, and it was first when I started the official client program a USB report was sent to the device, and it wasn't until after that I was able to analyze reports from the device which contained state information about both the button and the lid.

Comment: You might try using WireShark to resolve any parsing/format issues and buffering problems with `usbmon`.